# Inconsistent results in Spark-shell and Spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, spark-shell, spark2.4.4

I have a question.

I'm running a spark (scala) job via Oozie workflow and its giving me a slightly different result, whereas running the same spark code via spark-shell gives me the expected output.

While there is no change in the code, what makes the output different? Have any of you faced a situation like this in your project? Appreciating your comments.

P.S: I'm using spark 2.x. I'm not facing any error though while running as a Oozie job. Just the output difference is my concern.

Comment: Maybe you can add some details, like different how? Otherwise there are just too many possibilities I guess.

Comment: Umm.. I'm actually rewriting a Pig script to Spark. I am triggering this pig action and spark action in parallel via Oozie workflow. While comparing the results of the Pig script and spark script, I'm seeing some output data differences ( not a vast difference, just a little bit). So, to validate the spark code, I'm running it in **spark-shell**. The results of spark-shell is exactly the same as the Pig script's. So, while I didn't make any code changes, why the output is not the same then?

Comment: Just adding my thoughts, do you think that this parallel run can cause data integrity issues? Just a wild guess...

Comment: _"some output differences, just a little bit"_ doesnt clarify anything. No, parallel reads of the same data won't cause any issues. Perhaps you could run spark-shell and spark-submit with `-v` and compare the configurations that they use.